# Virtual layer with st_buffer from geopackage layer

Tags: spatialite, geopackage, virtual-layer

I'm trying to make a virtual layer that has a buffer over a layer of lines.
If I run the following query on a layer in shapefile it works correctly

```
create view river as select st_buffer(geometry,50) from BCN0302L_RIO_line where etiqueta = 'Río Sarela';
```

but if I run the same query on the same data but in a layer in geopackage or spatialite, the query gives no error but does not show the geometry in the canvas

What's wrong?

Comment: Is your geopackage layer in the same projection?

Comment: You are making a view? Show us the complete code to make the view. Is the view registered as a spatial view?

Comment: does is work without the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I tried to create the virtual layer in a virtual project in qgis 3.10 and other versions, but the result is the same.
The layer is in the same projection.

When I try to create a view in the geopackage database, it doesn't recognize it either with